# Jquery анимация сильно грузит процессор

Tags: jquery, оптимизация

Сделал вот такую анимацию на jquery.

```
function anima() {
    function eternalmotion() {
        $('.moon').animate({
            marginLeft: +parseInt($(document).width())
        }, 20000, 'linear',                
        function() {
            $('.moon').css({
                'marginLeft': $baseMoon
            });

        } );
        $('.stars_front').animate({
            backgroundPosition: -parseInt($(document).width())
        }, 30000, 'linear',                
        function() {
            $('.stars_front').css({
                'backgroundPosition': 0
            });
            //eternalmotion();
        } );
        $('.stars_back').animate({
            backgroundPosition: +parseInt($(document).width())
        }, 10000, 'linear',                
        function() {
            $('.stars_back').css({
                'backgroundPosition': 0
            });
            //eternalmotion();
        } );
        eternalmotion();
    }
    eternalmotion();
};
anima();
```

То есть двигаю я тут 3 слоя. Первый двигаю сам слой, другие 2 только background. Такая анимация сильно грузит процессор (90-95%) как мне ее оптимизировать? Или на jquery такого делать не стоит и лучше воспользоваться flash.

**UPD:**

Пробывал по разному как советовали в комментариях ничего прироста не дало. Появился новый вопрос если слой .stars_front и .stars_back имеют размеры 1200 на 400 и содержат в себе изображение такого разрешения может ли это вызывать лаги? Если я это изображение поделю на блоки будет ли выполнятся скрипт быстрее?

Comment: на первый взгляд ничего сворхпроизводительного нету, попробуйте воспользоваться специализированной библиотекой для анимации, например [Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/)

Comment: Этой "*специализированной библиотекой для анимации*", не советую пользоваться, если расчитываете на пользователей, у которых осел вплоть до девятой версии. А вот чего-то нагружающего не вижу так же. Закиньте на jsFiddle. Моежт с наглядым примером будет проще разобраться.

Comment: @greshnik, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но разве функция `eternalmotion()` не бесконечно вызывает сама себя без всяких задержек?

---

Запишу по другому:

```
function anima() {
    function eternalmotion() {
        $('.moon').animate(...);
        $('.stars_front').animate(...);
        $('.stars_back').animate(...);

        eternalmotion(); // <-- бесконечная рекурсия
    }
    eternalmotion();
};

anima();
```

---

Как же мне лень было этим заниматься, но только попробовав сам я понял что вам нужно. Нужно циклически запускать каждую анимацию по ее завершению, верно?...

Вот мое решение:

```
function anima() {
function animatemoon() {
    $('.moon').animate(
        {marginLeft: +parseInt($(document).width())},
        18000,
        'linear',                
        function() {$('.moon').css({'marginLeft': 0});animatemoon();}
    );
};

function animatestarsfront() {
    $('.stars_front').animate(
        {backgroundPosition: -parseInt($(document).width())},
        30000,
        'linear',           
        function() {$('.stars_front').css({'backgroundPosition': 0});animatestarsfront();}
    );
};

function animatestarsback() {
    $('.stars_back').animate(
        {backgroundPosition: +parseInt($(document).width())},
        10000,
        'linear',                
        function() {$('.stars_back').css({'backgroundPosition': 0});animatestarsback()}
    );
};

animatemoon();
animatestarsfront();
animatestarsback();
};
anima();
```

Мое творчество [все могут оценить тут](http://jsfiddle.net/2ageZ/1/) ))))))

Comment: Скорее всего эти задержки прописаны в исходнике jQuery функции .animate

Comment: нет, всё верно:

            eternalmotion(); // этот вызов явно лишний
        }
        eternalmotion();
    };
    anima();

Comment: без рекурсии анимация остановится, а мне этого не надо, дело тут точно в рекурсии

Comment: Возможно нужно вызывать функцию повторно после завершения предыдущей анимации или по какой-то задержке?

Comment: @greshnik, отредактировал ответ. попробуйте.

Answer (score 3):

Может стоит посмотреть в сторону [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Тогда код будет иметь вид примерно следующий:

```
function eternalmotion() {
    $.when( 
        $('.moon').animate(...),
        $('.stars_front').animate(...),
        $('.stars_back').animate(...)
    ).then(eternalmotion);
}
```

ещё вариант: выделить все 3 анимации в отдельные функции, которые вызывать в complete callback, каждой из них:

```
function moonAnimation(){
    $('.moon').animate(
        {
            marginLeft: +parseInt($(document).width())
        }, 
        20000, 
        'linear', 
        function() {
            $('.moon').css({
                 'marginLeft': $baseMoon
            });
            moonAnimation(); // будет вызвана как раз по завершении анимации
        }  
    );
}
```

То же самое проделать со всеми остальными анимациями.

Answer (score 2):

Уверен, что проблема в eternalmotion();
Функция много раз вызывается, JQ, не успевая обработать предыдущий вызов, зацикливается, что увеличивает нагрузку во много раз.

Answer (score 2):

Вот эту статью почитайте, там много про оптимизацию написано.

[Закрепляем jQuery — 25 отличных советов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/52201/).